# SQL - missing FROM clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I add an additional column in the select statement while using nested select statements

```
SELECT 
     MAX (mycount), people.name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         people.name a, COUNT(course_staff.staff) mycount
     FROM 
         course_staff, people
     WHERE 
         course_staff.staff = people.id
     GROUP BY 
         course_staff.staff,people.name) AS foo;
```

ERROR

> missing FROM-clause entry for table "people"
>   LINE 1: SELECT MAX (mycount), people.name

I want to add the people.name as well

Comment: Well, you gave an alias of `a` to `people.name`, so use that name instead. Also, you are counting `course_staff.staff`, but also grouping by it, what's the point on doing that?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using a `subquery` for `from` clause, try to alias it and use `alias` `prefix` for the `select` clause, also you have to use the aliases of subquery for the select statement in the outer query:

```
SELECT MAX (foo.mycount), foo.a
FROM (SELECT people.name a, -- use "a" also for outer query for column name
             COUNT(course_staff.staff) mycount -- use "mycount" in outer query
      FROM course_staff, people
      WHERE course_staff.staff = people.id
      GROUP BY people.name
     ) AS foo
GROUP BY foo.a
```